# Universal match and replace a pattern of arbitray length where only the beginning and end are known

Tags: python, regex, wildcard

I know that some variants of this question have been discussed, but they don't seem to work universally, as it were. Hence this question.

Say I have a text and within it appears, several times, this pattern:

> Let's start! ... blah, blah, blah... This is the end, my friend.

I want to replace every appearance of this pattern with

> Whatever.

The thing is - this pattern can be of any arbitrary length (other than its beginning and end), it may be stretched over one or more lines, and may contain with any number of special characters, including single and double quotes, slashes of all types, HTML tags, and other whatnots.

The expression will have to look for the starting phrase, collect it and everything the follows that phrase, regardless of how long it takes and what type of "stuff" is on the way, until it encounters the closing phrase, collects that too and replaces the whole thing with the replacement string; then do it again until it encounters the end of the text.

Is there any one (python) universal expression that will can do this kind of job?

Comment: What have you tried? startPattern.*endPattern is the general format that you want.

Comment: you mean like `re.sub("Let's start.*my friend",s,flags=re.DOTALL)` ?

Comment: exactly like that https://regex101.com/r/J8um0E/1

Comment: @Ajaypayne - I'm afraid not. If you change the pattern to "Let's start! ... blah, blah, blah...[new line]
How much longer? It's joe's place, isn't it? [another new line]
This is the end, my friend.", you get "no match, 38 steps".

Comment: So two things come to mind, 1 you said the beginning and end are known but then added more to the beginning and the end, and 2 this is XML, you can pass in the value of the node without the markup.

Comment: I only added text in the middle (replacing the blah, blah). The beginning ("Let's start!") and end ("This is the end, my friend.") are the same.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/J8um0E/3/ plus updated my answer.

Comment: @@Ajaypayne - wow it seems to work! I played with your example, added stuff before and after the pattern, and stuck in the middle of the pattern all sorts of junk, just to test it - and it still works! Is it really as simple as that? You have no idea how long I've been trying to figure this out... In the interest of future research, you should probably post it as a full answer (maybe with an explanation of how it works), so I could mark it answered. Thanks! Edit - I'm not fast enough - I see you did it while I was typing; great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just generated from the regex here - https://regex101.com/r/J8um0E/3/

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"Let's start(.*[\r\n])*.*my friend\."

test_str = ("Let's start! ... blah, blah, blah...\n"
    "How much longer? It's joe's place, isn't it?\n"
    "This is the end, my friend.")

subst = "Whatever."

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```